# Bot framework V4 500 - internal server error when deployed to azure (working with Ngrok/locally)

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, .net-5

I have a bot that fails to work when deployed to Azure. I'm running out of ideas on how to debug this as I'm not gathering enough information from console.

Bot is working perfectly fine using Ngrok. I'm using a separate channel for Azure deployment but configuration seems to be correct.

Endpoint is definitely getting hit as I can see 500 - internal server error every time I send a message to bot through teams.

Full error message in Azure portal "Log stream":

> ```
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    <head>
>   <title>IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error</title>
>   <style type="text/css">
>   </style>    </head>    <body>
>   <div id="content">
>      <div class="content-container">
>         <h3>HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error</h3>
>         <h4>The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.</h4>
>      </div>
>      <div class="content-container">
>         <fieldset>
>            <h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
>            <ul>
>               <li>IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of
> ```
>
> this error depends on which module handles the request and what was
> happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
>
> IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS
> permissions are set incorrectly.
>
> IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
>
> The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
>
> The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.
>
> ##### Things you can try:
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's
>   machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a
>   tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).
>
> ##### Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module
>    AspNetCoreModuleV2
>
>
> Notification
>    ExecuteRequestHandler
>
>
> Handler
>    aspNetCore
>
>
> Error Code
>    0x00000000
>
>
>
>
>
>
> Requested URL
>    https://indoc-chatbot-web-app:80/api/messages
>
>
> Physical Path
>    C:\home\site\wwwroot\api\messages
>
>
> Logon Method
>    Anonymous
>
>
> Logon User
>    Anonymous
>
> ##### More Information:
>
> This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server,
> but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
>
> [View
> more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393)
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

When testing in webchat, developer console shows 502 - bad gateway

> `POST https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/aaUT42gmEkL3Ow8evdgBY-a/activities 502`

Is there any other way I can debug this or maybe someone has any idea what could be causing this? Error might be coming from the code itself as I did have this working in the past and a lot has changed till then (but then again I am also using different endpoint channel so maybe it's an issue with configuration). I am developing my bot using .NET SDK. Deployment to Azure is done using Github CI/CD (configured in Azure).

Comment: Verify your Microsoft App id and password in azure as well as in your appsettings in the code, usually in emulator those information are not required to connect the chatbot. So probably these information are empty in your appsettings or contains invalid information.

Comment: @RajeeshMenoth you are right they aren't required in emulator but they are required when using azure channel with Ngrok. I did double check AppId/password and the combination matches. If it wouldn't my local code with Ngrok tunneling would not work.

Comment: Visual studio there is one option under view tab called as cloud explorer their you can connect and debug your code for live testing.

Answer (score 0):

[Rajeesh Menoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890048/rajeesh-menoth) said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074426/bot-framework-v4-500-internal-server-error-when-deployed-to-azure-working-wit/69264057#comment122103945_69074426):

> In Visual studio there is one option under view tab called as cloud explorer their you can connect and debug your code for live testing.

[image]

For more information please refer to the Microsoft documentation: [Troubleshoot HTTP 500 Internal Service Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-500-errors?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=dotnetwebapi).